# Getting Ajax error 500 when trying to post items from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

What I am trying to do is modify some attributes in my database.  The way I want to do it, is to have a dropdown menu that is populated with options (in this case, student names) from the table I am calling, and then populating text fields with the information that pertains to that specific student, that can then be edited and then submitted to the database.  So far, my drop down menu works.  It fills itself with the appropriate attributes.  My problem comes when I'm trying to populate the text fields with the other attributes.  I opened up the console to see if I was getting any errors (because nothing was happening after I selected a student) and it said there was an error 500 with my POST.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <?php                        
    # Perform database query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = $conn->query($query) or die('Query 1 failed: ' . mysql_error());

    ?>

    <label for="studentSelect">Student Name: </label>
    <select id="studentSelect">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['studentID'] . '" > "' . $row['studentFirstName'] . '"  "' . $row['studentLastName'] . '"</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <div>
        <label for="element_5_1">First Name</label>
        <input id="element_5_1" name="element_5_1" class="element text large" type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="floatLeft">
        <label for="element_5_3">Last Name</label>
        <input id="element_5_3" name="element_5_3" class="element text medium" style="width:14em" type="text">
        </span>

        <span style="float:left">
        <label for="element_5_4">Major</label>
        <input id="element_5_4" name="element_5_4" class="element text medium" style="width:4em" type="text">
        </select>
        </span>
        <span style="float:left">
        <label for="element_5_5">Credits Earned</label>   
        <input id="element_5_5" name="element_5_5" class="element text medium" style="width:6em" type="text">
        </span>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function makeAjaxRequest(studentFirstName)
    {
        $.ajax({        

        type: "POST",
        data: { studentFirstName: studentFirstName },
        dataType: "json", 
        url: "process_ajax.php",
        success: function(json) 
        {
            insertResults(json);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) 
        {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
        });
        }                               

        $("#studentSelect").on("change", function()
        {       
            var id = $(this).val();
            if (id === "0")
            {
                clearForm();
            }
            else 
            {
                makeAjaxRequest(id);
            }
        });                             

        function insertResults(json)
        {                                   

            $("#element_5_1").val(json["studentFirstName"]);

            $("#element_5_3").val(json["studentLastName"]);

            $("#element_5_4").val(json["major"]);

            $("#element_5_5").val(json["creditsEarned"]);
        }

        function clearForm()
        {
            $("#element_5_1, #element_5_3, #element_5_4, #element_5_5").val("");
        }

    </script>
```

I then have a separate ajax processing file

```
<?php
$host = "********.mysql.database.azure.com";
$username = "************";
$password = "*******";
$db_name = "**********";

//Establishes the connection
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());

$studentName = $_POST['studentFirstName'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM student";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query 2 failed: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($studentName == $row['studentFirstName']){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
?>
```

I hope I've given enough information for someone to be able to spot my errors. Thank you!

Comment: You're using this procedural style so I believe your `mysqli_query()` needs `$conn` as a first parameter: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)`

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `mysql_` and `mysqli_`.

Comment: @Kisaragi When I adjusted $result like you suggested, the whole page broke.  Before the adjustment, the dropdown was populated with items from the database, and the rest of the page loaded.  After the adjustment, the only the drop down menu loaded, but it had no attributes from the database loaded into it.

Comment: Are you using `mysql_` or `mysqli_`? Rather, which do you intend to use?

Comment: I thought I was using mysqli_? And if I'm not, that's what I want to use.

Comment: @Kisaragi is there a place in the main block of code where I am using mysql_ and not mysqli_?

Comment: see my updated code @JakimBeaufort

Answer (score 0):

Parse error line 22.

```
<?php
$host = "********.mysql.database.azure.com";
$username = "************";
$password = "*******";
$db_name = "**********";
//Establishes the connection
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)){
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());

    $studentName = $_POST['studentFirstName'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query 2 failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($studentName == $row['studentFirstName']){
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You have to change also your javascript

```
function insertResults(json)
{                                   
    $("#element_5_1").val(json.studentFirstName);

    $("#element_5_3").val(json.studentLastName);

    $("#element_5_4").val(json.major);

    $("#element_5_5").val(json.creditsEarned);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying theres a problem with my end php tag?

Comment: You forgot to close your if statement

Comment: Look at the difference between your code and the code i have posted. There is one more } in the end on my code.

Comment: Wow, ok that got rid of the 500 error, but the attributes still are not being posted to the text fields.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: There are rows inserted in your database?

Comment: Yeah, all the relevant tables are filled.  And I know that the attributes are being retrieved because the drop down menu is being populated by some of the attributes.  It's just that for some reason, when I'm trying to post them to the text field, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited my last post. There is an error in your javascript too. You have to access your json object like this json.studentFirstName

Comment: Ok so as I am doing this, I am making many console.log statements to see which parts of my code is being executed.  Before I tried your suggestion, I made an edit in my js. I changed data type- json to data type - text and all blocks of code got executed, but attributes still did not populate the text fields.  I tried your solution, without the modifictaion to datatype, but that made it so that not all of the code got executed

Comment: Can you tell me how does your json response data look like?

Comment: Can you tell me how I could get that? Sorry, I'm pretty new to web development, and I'm learning as I go

Comment: After adding more console logs, I found that my error is in my insert results function, specifically with these lines : `$("#element_5_1").val(json["studentFirstName"]);` The error I'm getting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: val` is not defined I get the same error even if I change the statement like you suggested to `$("#element_5_1").val(json.studentFirstName);`

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of trial and error, this is the code I came up with that works in populating the input fields. I'm pretty sure your error was the fact that your

```
<option value="' . $row['studentID'] . '" > "' . $row['studentFirstName'] . '"  "' . $row['studentLastName'] . '"</option>
```

should have been

```
<option value="' . $row['studentID'] . '" name="studentFirstName"> "' . $row['studentFirstName'] . '"  "' . $row['studentLastName'] . '"</option>
```

anyways onto my code:

**config.php**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = ""; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM messaging";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="studentSelect">Student Name: </label>
        <select id="studentSelect">
            <option value="0">Please select</option>
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['msg_id']; ?>" name="studentFirstName" id="studentFirstName">"<?php echo $row['msg_from'] ?>" "<?php echo $row['msg_to'] ?>"</option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <div>
            <span class="floatLeft">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input id="populate_first_name" class="element text large" type="text">
            </span>
            <span class="floatLeft">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input id="populate_last_name" class="element text medium" style="width:14em" type="text">
            </span>
            <span style="float:left">
                <label>Major</label>
                <input id="populate_major" class="element text medium" style="width:4em" type="text">
            </select>
            </span>
            <span style="float:left">
                <label>Credits Earned</label>   
                <input id="populate_credits_earned" class="element text medium" style="width:6em" type="text">
            </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#studentSelect").change(function(){
                    var studentFirstName = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'process_ajax.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {studentFirstName:studentFirstName},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(response) {
                            var len = response.length;
                            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                                var studentFirstName = response[i]['studentFirstName'];
                                var studentLastName = response[i]['studentLastName'];
                                var major = response[i]['major'];
                                var creditsEarned = response[i]['creditsEarned'];

                                $("#populate_first_name").val(studentFirstName);
                                $("#populate_last_name").val(studentLastName);
                                $("#populate_major").val(major);
                                $("#populate_credits_earned").val(creditsEarned);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process_ajax.php**

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$studentName = $_POST['studentFirstName'];   // department id

$sql = "SELECT * FROM student";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    if ($row['msg_id'] == $studentName) {
        $studentFirstName = $row['studentFirstName'];
        $studentLastName = $row['studentLastName'];
        $major = $row['major'];
        $creditsEarned = $row['creditsEarned'];

        $users_arr[] = array("studentFirstName" => $studentFirstName, "studentLastName" => $studentLastName, "major" => $major, "creditsEarned" => $creditsEarned);
    }
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
?>
```

Try it out and lemme know if it works

Comment: After adding more console logs, I found that my error is in my insert results function, specifically with these lines : `$("#element_5_1").val(json["studentFirstName"]);`  The error I'm getting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined`  I get the same error even if i change the statement like @Eduardo Nascimento Alves suggested to `$("#element_5_1").val(json.studentFirstName);`

Comment: I apologize for the very late response, but I tried it out and it wasn't working for me.  I thought maybe it had to do with the dropdown menu that you wrote (it was giving me errors because of the different php tags inside of it) so I switched it with the one you corrected in the beginning of the answer and it still wasn't working.  Also i changed out the msg_id value to studentID because that's an actual variable in my DB.  Nothing seems to get it going though.  I appreciate the time you took to write all of this

Comment: Ok, after making some console logs, I think I understand the problem.  Im trying to use studentFirstName to determine which DB info to use to populate the fields.  We accomplish this by taking the option value of the drop down and checking that against the info in the DB. I outputted the value of the first name to see if it was getting it, and it comes out as this `Bob name=` . The first name is always appended by " name=" if this is the case, then i think it will never work because no name in the DB has "name=" so it cant grab anything and post it to the fields.